How to embed password reset option inside my app without AD B2C token (user flows)
I am using AD B2C user flows,
I want to add to the account settings an option for the user to reset their password, but this option requires a token in the password rest url
is there a way to invoke an Azure function that gets the token and embed it to the url
or any other suggestion is welcome :-)
currently we are rediecting the users to the main signup/sign in page which includes the option of Password reset but I want the in-app url to take the users directly to the password reset link
